# .htaccess Rewrite not working while original URL does

Tags: .htaccess

On my website I only use the `public_html` to serve static files, and the index.php file acts as a sort of controller, loading files from another directory to make the structure a bit nicer.

My only issue is that the URLs wont function properly when rewritten.

The original url works, but the rewritten one doesn't because of the /.

Original URL  : `/index.php?page=auth/login`
Rewritten URL : `/auth/login`

Only the original one works, this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex specifically excludes paths with `/` in them. Try changing it to something very simple like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will match anything, excluding a trailing slash

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Now how would I make it work with another directory? (this below it: `RewriteRule ^api/(.*?)/?$ api.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]`), because it does not work like this and it will try to get the files from the web pages directory and not the API directory.

Comment: Put the `api` rule first since it's more specific